# How to make my comment form in Django to start working

Tags: python, django, web

I have a blog app and i am trying to add comments feature on the application, but it is not displaying properly, the comment form is suppose to display Name, Email and Body which is not showing...
this is the picture in my web app

[image]

Below is my view.py code

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView, CreateView,
                                  UpdateView, DeleteView)

from .models import Post
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm
from . import models



def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('post_detail')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',
                  {'form': form })

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 6

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')



class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

The models.py code below

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from groups.models import Group
from PIL import Image
import misaka

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True, default='/media/default-user.jpg')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (500, 500)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

Forms.py code also

```
from django import forms
from . import models
from .models import Post, Comment


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "group", "image")


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields["group"].queryset = (
                models.Group.objects.filter(
                    pk__in=user.groups.values_list("group__pk")
                )
            )

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

and finally the post_detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

        <article class="media content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'posts:user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                    {% if object.author == user %}
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'posts:post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'posts:post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                {% if object.image %}
                    <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" />
                {% endif %}
                <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>

              </div>
        </article>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1>{% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
                <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
                <p class="card-text ">{{ post.content | safe }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!-- comments -->
                <h2>{{ comments.count }} comments</h2>

                {% for comment in comments %}
                <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <p class="font-weight-bold">
                    {{ comment.name }}
                    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
                      {{ comment.created_on }}
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
              <div class="card-body">
                {% if new_comment %}
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                  Your comment is awaiting moderation
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
                <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                  {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Here is the post_detail.html codes

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

        <article class="media content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                    {% if object.author == user %}
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                {% if object.image %}
                    <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" />
                {% endif %}
                <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>

              </div>
        </article>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1>{% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
                <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
                <p class="card-text ">{{ post.content | safe }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!-- comments -->
                <h2>{{ comments.count }} comments</h2>

                {% for comment in comments %}
                <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <p class="font-weight-bold">
                    {{ comment.name }}
                    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
                      {{ comment.created_on }}
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
              <div class="card-body">
                {% if new_comment %}
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                  Your comment is awaiting moderation
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
                <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                  {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `Comment.active` is `False`.

In your view you filter the comments by `active=True`.

You need either change your filter, your default value or explicitly set `active = True` of your newly created Comment before you save it.